# Free SCORM data adapter

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have a LMS system which I want to upgrade to take in SCORM courses as well. What my approach is to read the SCORM course and get all necessary course elements (eg. CMI data models used, sequencing for SCOs etc.)  and play it with my own LMS. Are there any open source adapters that I can start to work with? Or what is the best approach to get started? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best idea on it is to first read the rules on xml file of your scorm and according to that rule make a database to match the scorm data and then with xml rule put those data into the database and use that database as your wish on your lms.

Comment: thanks @Anil but I'm looking for some plugin or adapters that will read the SCORM course and act as intermediate between my LMS and SCORM course.